# How to check if there is new data in API response?

Tags: ios, swift

Im creating two types of functionalities in my app, live status update for my order and social media integration too. I would like to know how to update data for these 2 situations as I want my UI to change automatically when there is change in API response. I have made them work but I'm not sure my approach is correct.

These are few situations I'm confused with:

1. I have to track my order using some status codes from `0 to 9` coming in API response and update UI based on status code, like for 0, say order received, for 1, order confirmed and so on.
   Right now I'm using timer to keep calling api again and again to check if there is any change in status in API response and reload tableview if there is.
2. I have opened all user posts page and first post on the screen is a post posted by me, and if someone likes my post on other device, is there any way to change likes count on my device without refreshing the page again?
   Again im using timer to call API and if there is new data, I reload my `UITableView`.
3. This is I got covered but just want clarity. In my social media post, if I click a post it opens `CommentViewController` showing comments, and if I click any comment then it opens `RepliesViewController` for all the replies and from any `UIViewController` you can tap userImage and open their profile. So if I like any post/comment/reply, im using delegates to make changes in other view controllers, so if I like a post in their profile, using delegates I'm adding like to post in `HomePage` for same `postId` but this approach increases number of delegates by a lot. It works fine but is there any way to tackle this situation with live updating API too like above two situations?

recently I worked with a `Socket` based chat app and it was easy to handle any live updates but is there any other way to get same functionality with my API's especially for that tracking feature?

Comment: 1. You could use (Silent) Push Notification to handle that. Whenever there is a change, you a notification, or use a WebSocket, since it's a "live action", like a chat. 2. You could check what changed from the new response, and do possible inserts in your data, an reload specific parts only of your `UITableView`. 3. You could use (Local) Notifications, a "Local Database", or have an array of delegates, and when you want to notify, you iterate over the array of delegatet, and call the method.

Comment: @Larme Will these silent push notification or websocket work with my api which is simply a post method api hit?

Comment: You need to implement the Push Notif on your server, and it will send a message to your app when there is new content (like order status did change). When you receive it, you can get info from it, and redo a call API to get new data.

Comment: @Larme so I will need to make changes at server end and its not possible with just calling  a get or post method based api. thanks

Comment: A basic GET/POST is a "one shot call" only, so no, you can't really... You want a socket based (ie, keep a connection alive and data comes from both ends), or use a way to trigger refresh (like posting a APNS from server), that will make the device do another call to get new data).

Comment: Yes thanks for clarifying. So I really need a socket for real time functionality